University Wifi blocks Mining traffic
I have several ASICs and GPUs that I want to use for mining, but the internet connection is blocking the activity. I’ve also tried using a hotspot, but for some reason, that gets blocked too.
What’s the best way to mine discreetly? Are there mining software or pools that support proxies, or would using a VPN be a better solution? If I go the VPN route, how can I connect all my miners to it effectively?
